# django filebrowser not allowing folders to be created and does not upload files

Tags: django, file-permissions, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser, django-grappelli

I'm trying to implement django-filebrowser into my latest app. I have grappelli installed also. The urls work fine for getting into filebrowser /admin/filebrowser/browse is what I have it set at.

The problem I am having is when it comes to trying to either add a folder or upload a file.

**New Folder:**

When I'm adding a folder an error is thrown stating:

> **Please correct the following errors.**
>
> Permission denied.

Now the permissions for the folder are fine. I don't understand why it won't allow me to upload files here.

> drwxr-xr-x 2 naytive naytive 4096 Jan 18 08:32 uploads/

**Upload File:**

Normally when uploading a file, the filebrowser upload screen appears with a timer to upload success, however when I try to upload a file it just refreshes the page with url ending

> ?_save=Upload

It is getting to the point where I will just remove the module because it isn't doing as it is set up to be.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I think the uploading files side of things is caused by the original file permissions also. If we fix this error then perhaps the upload will work too.

Comment: "Now the permissions for the folder are fine."  What about the parent folders?  Each parent must have "X" permission.

Comment: How far back do the permissions need to go? as the parent is also set to 755

Comment: Permissions set to 755 is not enough if Django process runs under another user than naytive or not part of naytive group. Are you testing it with the dev server ?

Comment: I'm not testing it with the dev server no its running on mod_wsgi, how would i check what user is trying to run it. As far as I am aware it should be naytive.

Comment: is FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS set in your settings? After updating filebrowser I had a similar problem, it seemed to be whenever a new folder was created? adding the settings seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use it on a server with apache, then you must give apache right to write in this folder (`chown`).

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar. I gave permission to **www-data** user to the folder i wanted to upload to and it worked.

Comment: so your referring to chown www-data ?

Comment: I guess so. I have a gui interface so I don't know the actual command. I had to chown 777 the dir and give the www-data user and group permission to write.